# Will Googlebot read microformat data inserted via javascript?

Tags: javascript, googlebot, microformats

I have already tried Google's microformat testing tool, but it's not clear to me that it works the same way as Googlebot -- it seems reasonable that Googlebot would have more features than a simple web-based testing tool.

So, I'm wondering -- does anyone have any real-world experience in successfully getting Googlebot to parse microformat data inserted via javascript (e.g., external script via document.write).

Any kind of authoritative source would be great. I'm flying completely blind on this one right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Google's web crawler will not execute Javascript on the page.  Your microformat is not getting written or interpreted by the Googlebot.

Answer (score 1):

We need to update this answer. Ned's answer was correct at the time, but [Google can now execute JS and AJAX](http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518), according to SearchEngineLand, which I'm taking to imply that, yes, microdata will be read by GoogleBot if generated in the Javascript.

Sorry - I don't have real-world experience yet - I'm just getting to microdata 3 years after @tbarkow, but SearchEngineLand has always been pretty reliable. Same with [SearchEngineWatch](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2122137/Googlebot-Learns-to-Read-AJAXJavaScript-Comments).